# How to calculate epoch month?

Tags: datetime, epoch

I just asked how to calculate epoch day [How to calculate epoch day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975472/how-to-calculate-epoch-day) - probably should haver asked this at the same time.  Anyhoo....

How do I calculate epoch month? By "epoch month" I mean "the current month is the Xth month since the epoch". X is an integer.

Comment: It is time for you to learn how to think for yourself.  You now know how to calculate the number of days since The (UNIX, POSIX) Epoch from your previous question.  It isn't dreadfully hard to work out which year you're in given the number of days since The Epoch, and then which month you're in within that year.  You have a brain; you are allowed to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate epoch day?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975472/how-to-calculate-epoch-day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JonathonLeffler ok point taken.

epochmonth = ((current year number - 1970 - 1) * 12) + current month number

Comment: Is this correct? I believe the correct calculation is  ((current year number - 1970) * 12) + current month number. For the current month (as of July 2020)  this gives me 606 = ((2020 - 1970) * 12) + 6

Comment: Agree with @robotdan I doesn't understand why you deduct one after 1970. 
The question is if you want to start your counting from zero (meaning month from epoch = 0 for 1970-01-01) in this case the calculation is:
((current year number - 1970) * 12) + current month number -1  

Example: 2021-04-21: [(2021-1970)*12]+4-1 = 616