# MongoDB $concatenate Date Error

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, pymongo-2.x, database

I am working on a mongo aggregation project to group average readings every two hours which returns the desired output as follows

```
{
        "_id": {
            "Year": 2016,
            "locationID": " WL 001",
            "Day": 25,
            "Hour": 12,
            "Month": 1
        },
        "temperature": 10.858749999999999,
        "pH": 0,
        "Conductivity": 2032.375
    }
```

I want to regroup the data format and concatenate the date portion of the _id field so that it represent a new data format format below

```
{
    "_id": {
       "locationID": " WL 001",
    },
    "Readings": {
        "temperatue": {
            "value": 8.879
        },
        "SensoreDate": {
            "value": "2016-01-25:12"
        },
        "pH": {
            "value": 16.81
        },
        "Conductivity": {
            "value": 1084
        }
    },
}
```

Here is the $project portion of my aggregation query

```
{
    "$project": {
        '_id': '$_id.locationID',
        'Readings': {
            'pH': {'value': '$pH'},
            'temperature': {'value': '$temperature'},
            'Conductivity': {'value': '$Conductivity'},
            'SensoreDate': {'value': {'$concat': ["$_id.Year", "$_id.Month", "$_id.Day", "$_id.Hour"]} }
        }
    }
}
```

but i am getting an error **$concat only supports strings, not NumberInt32** I have tried several options but can not get it to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb concat int and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891511/mongodb-concat-int-and-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use concat with substr to join them into a date.

```
'SensoreDate': {
    'value': {
        '$concat': [{
                $substr: ["$_id.Year", 0, -1]
            },
            "-", {
                $substr: ["$_id.Month", 0, -1]
            },
            "-", {
                $substr: ["$_id.Day", 0, -1]
            },
            ":", {
                $substr: ["$_id.Hour", 0, -1]
            }
        ]
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Conversion of int to str will not be possible in the pipeline. So `$concat` wont be possible on for the given data format.

Another method which could work would be ***trick*** to convert the year, month, day into a BSON `Date` format object.

The inspiration is that `dateObj: {$add: [new Date(0), '$time_in_sec_epoch']}`.

The calculation of `$time_in_sec_epoch` can be done using aggregation operators like `$sum`, `$divide`, `$subtract` etc. You can use the formula as given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21975574/1273742). This will be tedious, but hopefully you get the idea.

For the `dateObj` to a string part use `$dateToString`